# "Uniform" convergence over Stolz angles

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on this problem on analysis of function families.  It is from the conformal maps chapter in Gamelin.

Let $f(z)$ be bounded, analytic on $D = \{|z| < 1\}$.  Show that if $f(re^{i\theta}) \rightarrow L$ as $r \rightarrow 1$ (for fixed $\theta$), then $f(z) \rightarrow L$ uniformly as $z \rightarrow e^{i\theta}$ through any cone with vertex at $e^{i\theta}$ (centered on the radius with angle less than $\pi$ radians).

I don't know how to start the problem apart from making explicit the given hypotheses.  I'm not even sure what is meant by uniform convergence.  There is no sequence or family of functions involved...it's just a function $f$?

Comment: It's from the normal family section. So you have to employ "normal family" arguments.